# Can an Array element be equal to an integer’s name and not value?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

Example:

```
int k = 5;
int array [] = {1, 2, 3, k, 5};

if ((array[3]) == k) { //(or .equals)
…
…
}
```

Basically, I want to see if the element is on K, not if the element value equals K.

Comment: ............No.

Comment: You can not have `characters` in `int` array.

Comment: You probably need an array of Integer objects.  With objects == tests if they are the same object, equals tests if they are equal in value.  Problem is you end up with a mish mash of some parts using Integer  and some parts using int.

Answer (score 0):

//basically I want to see if the element is on K not if the element value equals K.

-> for that you have to check for the index.

so like this:

```
int k = 5;
int[] array = {1,2,3,k,5};

if(array[k] == k)
{
  System.out.println("yes the int value k is at index k");
}
```

BUT: In this case it would give an IndexOutOfBounce error, as the index it's checkiung for (5) is greater than the length of the array (which is 5, but the last index is 4 as we start from 0).

ALSO: You need == and not equals, as int values are not objects.